# how can i decode animated webp with android 4.0+

Tags: android, animated, webp

Use webp like this

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.raw.webp);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

webp is ok. but animated webp can not decode bitmap.